# Cannot insert JSON data from Mongoose into MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to persist the following json data, the document is being created in Mongo with an id without the data.

Data:

```
{
    "delivery": "{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Public\",\"email\":\"john@public.com\",\"phone\":\"5555555555\",\"shippingAddress\":\"40 Beauman Plaza\",\"city\":\"Anchorage\",\"state\":\"AK\",\"zip\":\"55555\",\"deliveryDate\":\"2017-07-29T04:00:00.000Z\",\"deliveryInstruction\":\"Deliver it today\"}",
    "payment": "{\"creditCardNo\":9898767876545432,\"creditCardYear\":\"2025\",\"creditCardMonth\":\"11\",\"cws\":\"111\",\"paymentType\":\"\"}",
    "orderProduct": "[{\"productId\":\"5962a568734d1d256343a213\",\"quantity\":1},{\"productId\":\"596161e1734d1d25634366ce\",\"quantity\":1},{\"productId\":\"5962a545734d1d256343a20e\",\"quantity\":1},{\"productId\":\"5962a5ac734d1d256343a221\",\"quantity\":1}]"
}
```

Mongoose code to insert data into Mongo:

```
  router.post('/order/add', function(req, res) {
  var order = req.body.order; 

  var newOrder = new Order({
    delivery: req.body.delivery,
    payment: req.body.payment,
    orderProduct: req.body.orderProduct        
  });
  newOrder.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).json(newOrder);
  })    
})
```

Result created in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5971e49e777cab0f18456da9"
    },
    "orderProduct": [],
    "payment": [],
    "delivery": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Mongoose Model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DeliverySchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  shippingAddress: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  zip: String,
  deliveryDate: Date,
  deliveryInstruction: String});

var PaymentSchema = new Schema({
  creditCardNo: String,
  creditCardYear: String,
  creditCardMonth: String,
  cws: String,
  paymentType: String})

var OrderProductSchema = new Schema({
  productId: Number,
  quantity: Number});

var OrderSchema = new Schema({
  delivery: DeliverySchema,
  payment: PaymentSchema,
  orderProduct: [OrderProductSchema]});

var Order = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema, "order");
module.exports = Order;
```

Angular call to persist data:

```
placeOrder() {
  let orderData = new Order();
  orderData.delivery = JSON.stringify(this.deliveryForm.getRawValue());
  orderData.payment = JSON.stringify(this.paymentForm.getRawValue());
  orderData.orderProduct = this.cartService.getOrderProduct();
  var order = JSON.stringify(orderData);    
  console.log(order);
  this.checkoutService.placeOrder(order)
}
```

Http call:

```
placeOrder(order) {
  this.http.post(this.orderUrl, {order: order})
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => console.log('result = ' + res.json().data as string))
  // .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  // .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Those look like "strings" rather than something that would be parsed to an object. So it looks like your code sending the serialized data is incorrect. But that code is of course not included in the question.

Comment: I have added the code sending the data.

Comment: In OrderSchema, you are declaring `delivery` to be an array of `DeliverySchema`, I feel it should just be `DeliverySchema` instead of `[DeliverySchema]`

Comment: You are right on that. I have fixed it. But that doesn't seem to be the source of the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, think the problem is in `JSON.stringify`. Try remove it from angular and send as `Content-type: 'application/json'` or `JSON.parse` in express controller.